# laravel eloquent store submodel with model

Tags: model, eloquent, laravel-5.4, relation

If a user creates an account, I want to store default settings in a different table. I have two models: `User` and `UserSettings` .

How to create the settings part after creating the User?

I create the User as follow:

```
  $user = User::create([
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
```

Then I tried:

```
$user->settings()->save(new UserSettings());
```

I also tried the `create` method, but with no success. I always receive

> ErrorException in HasAttributes.php line 818: Illegal offset type

in `User::class` model i have

```
public function settings()
{
    return $this->hasOne(UserSetting::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

and the inverse in `UserSetting::class`

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id', 'user_id');
}
```

`user_settings` table

> settings_id | user_id | different_options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the below code and its worked. Please have a look.

```
    $user = new User;
    $user->username = "JicksonJohnson";
    $user->email = "jicksonkoottala@gmail.com";
    $user->password = bcrypt('123456');
    $user->save();
    $user->settings()->save(new UserSettings(array('user_id' => $user->id,'options' => 'test options')));
```

In User model I created one relationship.

```
public function settings()
{
    return $this->hasOne(UserSettings::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

Comment: Dumb me, i set the primary key in the `UserSetting::class` to an array instead of a string. But your solution works as aspected!